# Can Mac OS X's Core Animation let you change the layout of the screen?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I have been reading up on OS X's Core animation. I would like to know if it is possible to control the OS windows in a similar way to Expose, Time Machine, and or switching user screens. I am aware that it is possible to easily do these effects in your own program. But if one wanted to control Safari's browser windows, let's say, is that possible? I'm having trouble finding thorough information about the "Compositor" (not Composer), Core Animation's API, and other OS windowing details.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do with publicly available API is limited. What's public can be found in the [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Introduction.html).

For non-public routines, google [CGWindow+Quartz](http://www.google.com/search?q=cgwindow+quartz) or [CGSWindow+Quartz](http://www.google.com/search?q=cgswindow+quartz).

And you can always inject code to windowserver if you're brave enough. But that's not easy.